# Astropy WCS: "IOError: Header missing END card."

Tags: python, python-2.7, astropy

I'm trying to convert WCS to pixels using [astropy](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/wcs/), but when I try to read in the image:

```
from astropy import wcs

w = wcs.WCS('image_file.fits')
```

I get the following Exception:

```
*WARNING: Unexpected extra padding at the end of the file.  This padding may not be preserved when saving changes. [astropy.io.fits.header]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_stamps.py", line 29, in <module>
    w = wcs.WCS(image_file)
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/wcs/wcs.py", line 385, in __init__
    fobj = fits.open(header)
  Fhttp://stackoverflow.com/posts/41513868/editile "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 139, in fitsopen
    return HDUList.fromfile(name, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 281, in fromfile
    save_backup=save_backup, cache=cache, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/hdulist.py", line 839, in _readfrom
    hdu = _BaseHDU.readfrom(ffo, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/base.py", line 423, in readfrom
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/base.py", line 483, in _readfrom_internal
    header = Header.fromfile(data, endcard=not ignore_missing_end)
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/header.py", line 451, in fromfile
    padding)[2]
  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/header.py", line 520, in _from_blocks
    raise IOError('Header missing END card.')
IOError: Header missing END card.*
```

I got this error before when using just [`fits.open()`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/files.html#open) but was able to solve the problem by adding `"ignore_missing_end=True"`. But, `"ignore_missing_end"` doesn't seem to be a argument of the wcs class. How can the image be read with `astropy.wcs.wcs`?

Comment: I think the `WCS` initializer can take an already open file as an argument instead of a filename, so you might try that for starters. The "missing END card" error suggests a likely malformatted file though, so you might also try opening it with ignore_missing_end=True like you did before, and writing out a new copy of the file. Sometimes that can fix minor formatting problems in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [`astropy.wcs.WCS`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.wcs.WCS.html#astropy.wcs.WCS) can take a filename is just a convenience option so it's not really surprising that you can't pass (all) parameters that [`astropy.io.fits.open`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/files.html#open) accepts to this function as well.

However it's quite easy to create a `WCS` with a [`astropy.io.fits.Header`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/headers.html#header). So you can open the file, extract the relevant header and create the WCS yourself:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

with fits.open('your_file.fits', mode='readonly', ignore_missing_end=True) as fitsfile:
    # if you want the first extension, otherwise change the [0].
    wcs = WCS(fitsfile[0].header)  
# Now you can use your WCS, for example:
print(wcs)
```